# Google developer console project creation error

Tags: android, google-developers-console

While creating project on google developer console, I'm getting **Project name is Invalid**" error

Is it because of `googlesignin` in the package?

[image: thi is the error I'm getting]
[image: this is manifest]

Comment: I think the issue is you are using name googlesignin try to change the package name.

Comment: I've tried that too, i tried "com.dell.example" as package name but no luck

Comment: You can't use the word 'example' too.. Try to be creative with your work.

Comment: Resolved now. I download ed the required google play service files through Sdk manager, with the package name as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Package name or your App Name is responsible for the error.

- It could be because of `googlesignin` in your package.

**Try changing it**.

Try Using a **Unique/Valid** Package Name,

Use your Creativity in your Package Name.

Comment: Don't include keywords like googlesignin or dell in your package...try something like com.example.mayuri..etc and tell me its working or not

Comment: You can't use the word "example" too, playstore won't accept it.

Comment: @UniqueIdentifier Yes...By "example",I mean any random or valid keyword...

Comment: Yaps right you should mention it because the person already confused with which words to use.

Comment: With the word 'example' the project got created. I downloaded google play services files from sdk manager. Still i don't understand how this error is related to downloding google play services files

Comment: @mayurikulkarni Glad your problem solved..The problem occurred  because you are using "googlesignin" keyword in your package.